# How to run Fujitsu P27T-7 LED monitor in its not native resolution and have perfect fonts rendering

Tags: fonts, resolution, rendering

My problem is completely opposite to anything I could find as I need to run my monitor in its NOT native resolution and have perfect font rendering.

I recently got myself Ultra HD 2560x1440 27 inch monitor (Fujitsu P27T-7 LED) and I have an issue with this. I would call it personal but I'm afraid it's not as few people already agreed with me. I do programming and the text on UHD is way to small for comfortable usage. I changed the resolution to regular Full HD (1920x1080), it became just right but the text is looking slightly blur now, in comparison to both its natural UHD resolution and/or to my old 23 inch NEC.

I am pretty frustrated and not sure what to do and how to make fonts look just as sleek as they should? I can't work in UHD resolution (my vision is 100% perfect), simply if calculated, picture size with Ultra HD (2560x1440) on 27 inch is around 30% smaller than Full HD (1920x1080) on 23 inch. In order to have same font size, if compared with Full HD 23 inch, 27 inch Ultra HD monitor must be around 32 inches in size.

If I set my new monitor to regular Full HD 1920x1080, then the fonts' size are just perfect but the quality is not as it's blurry?

Could anyone please help me out with an advise of how to solve this problem?

*Spec:*
nVidia 560 Ti with DVI-D port on Fedora 20.

#### EDIT 1:

Changing fonts doesn't really help as everything else doesn't look the way it should.

#### EDIT 2:

The monitor is buzzing on 2560x1440 so badly in case there are lots of lines on the screen, like file listing. If I type `ls /usr/bin` it makes such nasty irritating sound. When resolution goes to 1920x1080 it's a bit better. Any idea why?

Comment: A certain blur is unavoidable because of the non-native resolution. The monitor gets 1920 pixels per line and has to display them on 2560 real pixels, so it has to blur (interpolate) 3x3 pixels into 4x4. The only solution would be to use native resolution and increase the font size.

Comment: Why not just increase the font size?